# Different color when node is contained in rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{parrows, arrows.meta, math, matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  vertex/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=0, minimum size=0.12cm}
  ]
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} {
    \foreach \y  in {0,1,...,7} {
      \node at (\x*0.4,\y*0.4) [vertex, color=blue] {};
    }
  }
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,3} {
    \foreach \y  in {0,1,...,3} {
      \node at (\x*0.5+0.35,\y*0.5+0.55) (O\x\y)[vertex, draw=none, fill=orange] {};
    }
  }
  \node[draw, dashed, color=orange, minimum size=2.35cm, thick] (BB) at (1.1,1.3) {};
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which paints a bunch of blue nodes and some orange nodes. The orange nodes are surrounded by an orange rectangle BB.

- How can I change the color of just the blue nodes that are contained in the orange rectangle?
- Is there a more clever way to position the orange rectangle exactly at the middle points of the orange nodes?

Thanks!

Comment: What should be the color if the blue circle intersects the orange rectangle? It should be green if and only if totally inside the rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the second point is to use the `fit` library and just say `fit=(O00)(O33)`. For the first point you can either use conditions on `\x` and `\y` and change the `color=` accordingly, or easier (but not the most efficient) draw a rectangular `clip` path and put the green nodes inside it.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  vertex/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=0, minimum size=0.12cm}
  ]
  \newcommand{\drawcircles}[1]{%
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} {
    \foreach \y  in {0,1,...,7} {
      \node at (\x*0.4,\y*0.4) [vertex, color=#1] {};
    }
  }}
  \drawcircles{blue}
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,3} {
    \foreach \y  in {0,1,...,3} {
      \node at (\x*0.5+0.35,\y*0.5+0.55) (O\x\y)[vertex, draw=none,  fill=orange] {};
    }
  }
  \node[draw, dashed, color=orange, thick, fit=(O00)(O33)] (BB){};
  \path [clip] (BB.north west) rectangle (BB.south east);
  \drawcircles{green,thick}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

And the conditionals approach:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}    % <---
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  vertex/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=0, minimum size=0.12cm}
  ]
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} {
    \foreach \y  in {0,1,...,7} {
      \ifthenelse{\x>0\AND\x<6 \AND \y>0\AND\y<6}            % condition 
        {\node at (\x*0.4,\y*0.4) [vertex, color=green] {};} % true
        {\node at (\x*0.4,\y*0.4) [vertex, color=blue] {};}  % false    
    }
  }
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,3} {
    \foreach \y  in {0,1,...,3} {
      \node at (\x*0.5+0.35,\y*0.5+0.55) (O\x\y)[vertex, draw=none,  fill=orange] {};
    }
  }
  \node[draw, dashed, color=orange, thick, fit=(O00)(O33)] (BB){};
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Nice! I'd improve using `\newcommand{\xmax}{3} \newcommand{\ymax}{3}` for example, to have more flexibility, as I was doing in my deleted answer.

Comment: If we add one more orange column making the orange `\x` from `0` to `4`, there will be one more blue column inside the rectangle. But they still are blue!

Comment: Yes, the numbers in the condition can be made more precise or even as a parameter of `\O00` and `O33`, but the idea is still there.

Answer (score 2):

After discussing with @marmot, I fixed my idea and now there are 8 values to pass. To help, I created commands

```
\gridBlue{xmin}{xmax}{ymin}{ymax}
\gridOrange{xmin}{xmax}{ymin}{ymax}
```

so that the circles create the lattices `[xmin,xmax] \times [ymin,ymax]` (blue and orange).

Also, observe that *if* the circle touch the rectangle, it is not considered *inside* so remains blue.

Finally, the **most important** parts are `\x <= \xmaxOrange + 1` and `\y <= \ymaxOrange + 2` where the addition **should be adjusted** depending the perturbation of the orange circles.

**Remark:** the OP multiply the node coordinates by a factor and translate them; this process makes difficulty to automatically compute the perturbation factor.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

% grid format
% [#1,#2] \times [#3,#4]
\newcommand{\gridBlue}[4]{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xminBlue}{#1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xmaxBlue}{#2}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yminBlue}{#3}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ymaxBlue}{#4}
}

\newcommand{\gridOrange}[4]{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xminOrange}{#1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xmaxOrange}{#2}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yminOrange}{#3}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ymaxOrange}{#4}
}

\begin{document}
% [1,7] \times [1,6]
\gridBlue{1}{7}{1}{6}
% [2,4] \times [1,3]
\gridOrange{2}{4}{1}{3}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
vertex/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=0, minimum size=0.12cm}
]
\foreach \x in {\xminBlue,...,\xmaxBlue} {
\foreach \y in {\yminBlue,...,\ymaxBlue} {
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{ifthenelse(\x >= \xminOrange+2 && \x <= \xmaxOrange+1  && \y >= \yminOrange+2 && \y <= \ymaxOrange+2, "green","blue")}
\node at (\x*0.4,\y*0.4) [vertex, color=\mycolor] {};
}
}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=BB]
\foreach \x in {\xminOrange,...,\xmaxOrange} {
\foreach \y in {\yminOrange,...,\ymaxOrange} {
\node at (\x*0.5+0.35,\y*0.5+0.55) [vertex, draw=none, fill=orange] {};
}
}
\end{scope}
\draw[color=orange, thin]
([xshift=-1pt,yshift=-1pt]BB.south west) rectangle ([xshift=1pt,yshift=1pt]BB.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** the image below is to show how translation affects the orange grid: the black arrow points from `(\xminOrange*0.5,\yminOrange*0.5)` to `(\xminOrange*0.5 + .35,\yminOrange*0.5 + .55)`.

[image]